# Hibernate hbm2dao

Tags: hibernate

while generating DAO classes using hbm2dao, is it possible to provide a custom package name and class name. I don't want to use the Home.java and the default package. By tweaking the template, I can change the name of the class in the java file where it says

```
public class <classname>DaoImpl
```

But don't know how to change the name of the file itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this issue, i just used ant to rename that file and move it.